# Parallax Scrolling for WordPress Site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parallax

I'm currently building a custom WordPress theme with parallax scrolling included in the design. The final "product" is supposed to be exactly like this website: templetondistillery.com. There is a section where there is a row of 3 images and they flow together via parallax. However, I have NO IDEA how to do this and can't seem to find a good solution. Does any know of any plugins or javascript libraries or better yet, just a general solution to this functionality?

Comment: Looking at the source code for that distillery site, it looks like it uses ScrollMagic for what at least some of their parallax effects, so I'd start there (note, i know nothing about this library, so i can't really provide additional support) https://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_scrolling.html

Comment: ...and there's other references to Swiper JS and parallax:
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parallax

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry, but this question is off-topic here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic specifically - `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`